# Array.select with optional conditionals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Array of Hashes

```
[
{ :user_id => 123,
  :start_date => Date,
  :end_date => Date
},
{ :user_id => 345,
  :start_date => Date,
  :end_date => Date
},
...
]
```

I want to select some of the objects based on optional parameters, say if `params[:user_id]`, `params[:start_date]`, `params[:end_date]` is optionally passed from the controller. How do I include multiple conditionals within a single `.select` statement.

```
Array.select do |arr|
   arr[:user_id] == params[:user_id] if params[:user_id] &&
       arr[:start_date] >= params[:start_date] if params[:start_date] &&
       arr[:end_date] <= params[:end_date] if params[:end_date]
end
```

wasn't working as intended. The 2nd and 3rd conditional is ignored.

Comment: You should update this question to include runnable code. We can't help trouble shoot pseudo code; questions are expected to contain the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem

Comment: Naming your array `Array` is a bad idea, and not just because `Array` is a constant. After naming your array try creating a new array with 3 elements: `Array.new(3)`.

Comment: Actually, your DBM is the right place to do the select, not in code after you retrieved the entire DB. An array of hashes, where each hash has a different `user_id` is not a good choice for your container. Simply use a hash where each key is the `user_id` value, and the remaining fields are the value of that key. `{ 123 => {start_date: Date, end_date: Date}, 345 => {start_date: Date, end_date: Date} }`. See "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)"

Comment: @theTinMan the source is a JSON file that I don't have control over.

Comment: That may be, but once data, like that JSON, has been ingested by your code you have total control over it. My first step would be to massage it into something more useful. If it's an easy fit in memory I'd keep it there, otherwise I'd immediately export it to a database where the DBM can handle all the heavy lifting.

Comment: @theTinMan noted. Thanks for the tip. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern I like to use is `next`. This is basically a way to 'return early' from the block, and split up your conditions into multiple statements. Just make sure you add a `true` at the end so that if the item passes all the validations, it will be included in the result.

```
result = array.select do |item|
  if params[:user_id]
    next if item[:user_id] != params[:user_id]
  end
  if params[:start_date]
    next if item[:start_date] <= params[:start_date]
  end
  if params[:end_date]
    next if item[:end_date] >= params[:end_date]
  end
  true
end
```

you could of course change all these `if .. else` blocks to one liners if you prefer:

```
result = array.select do |item|
  next if params[:user_id] && item[:user_id] != params[:user_id]
  next if params[:start_date] && item[:start_date] <= params[:start_date]
  next if params[:end_date] && item[:end_date] >= params[:end_date]
  true
end
```

Comment: This solution worked. The second block of code is neat. Thanks!